# Yum Updates over 443 Instead of 80

Tags: centos

I am admin on some CentOS servers but not admin on our network firewall. The FW admins are now blocking port `80` outbound and only allowing `443` outbound.

How can I run yum software updates and install packages with yum over port 443 instead?

Comment: All I had to do is simply Google "centos yum https" and voila : https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=68451 . You don't say what version of CentOS you use, but those links should help anyway.